# What are the steps needs to followed to make an object immutable?

Tags: java

Could any one explain what are the steps needs to be followed to make an object immutable?

I found these guidelines. Please correct me if I am missing anything.

1. Don’t provide “setter” methods — methods that modify fields or objects referred to by fields.
2. Make all fields final and private
3. Don’t allow subclasses to override methods

Many Thanks.

Comment: Prefix it with `final` ?

Comment: have you tried adding the keyword `final` before its definition?

Comment: What do you mean? Just add the keyword `final`.

Comment: Do you mean immutable?

Comment: yes... correct immutable...

Comment: I found these guidelines... please correct me if i am missing anything.                                                           1. Don’t provide “setter” methods — methods that modify fields or objects referred to by fields. 2. Make all fields final and private 3. Don’t allow subclasses to override methods

Comment: have you tried a simple google search? http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEy06R8iaAg

Comment: Dear Manny264, i am aware of the concept. Since I haven't get a chance to use it i am looking for exact steps to implement that. Its just not ends with putting final keyword to make an object immutable. Hope you can appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

"Use the keyword final in the class declaration:

```
public final class SomeClass {
  //  . . . Class contents
}
```

"

Answer (score 1):

Java class with final modifier is called final class in Java. Final class is complete in nature and can not be sub-classed or inherited. Several classes in Java are final e.g. String, Integer and other wrapper classes. Here is an example of final class in java

```
final class PersonalLoan{

}

class CheapPersonalLoan extends PersonalLoan{  
 //compilation error: cannot inherit from final class

}
```